# Order By Two Columns Simultaneously SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle11g

I have a SQL question about how my query output is being ordered.

Here is how the output looks now:

```
REFERRED_FROM     REFERRED_FROM_COUNT     REFERRED_TO     REFERRED_TO_COUNT
sample            sample number
sample            sample number
sample            sample number
                                          sample          sample number
                                          sample          sample number
                                          sample          sample number
```

And here is my desired output:

```
REFERRED_FROM     REFERRED_FROM_COUNT     REFERRED_TO     REFERRED_TO_COUNT
sample            sample number           sample          sample number
sample            sample number           sample          sample_number
sample            sample number           sample          sample number
```

I'm fairly new to SQL scripting but I'm fairly certain this is doable and I'm not sure why I can't figure it out.

Right now I have 4 case statements in my select statement, ending as Referred_From, Referred_From_Count, etc... and I am Ordering By Referred_From and id numbers. My output data is correct, the formatting however is off. Is this an easy fix or will I have to re-do the base of how I am going about this?

Thanks in advance, I look forward to figuring this out.

Comment: You will not be able to do this just with ordering. You will have to change your select statement

Comment: This is not just an "ordering" issue. You are showing your query is returning *six* rows; that can not be converted to *three* rows with an `ORDER BY` clause. (You can't figure out how to do that because it's impossible.) You will need to make more significant changes to your query, or handle the "reformatting" of the result in the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help! I was able to get it done most efficiently using CTE's. I also used Lukas Eder's way as practice, so thank you for posting that.

Long story short I did this:

```
WITH ref_from as ........

WITH ref_to as ..........

SELECT Referred_From, Referred_From_Count, Referred_To, Referred_To_Count
FROM (select rownum rowfrom, ref_from.* from ref_from) t1,
     (select rownum rowto, ref_to.* from ref_to) t2
WHERE rowfrom = rowto;
```

I created the 'rowfrom' and 'rowto' so I had something to join the two together with and it worked perfectly.

Thanks again, I really appreciate the tips.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
SELECT referred_from, referred_from_count, referred_to, referred_to_count
FROM (
  SELECT referred_from, referred_from_count, rownum r
  FROM my_table
  WHERE referred_from IS NOT NULL
  AND referred_from_count IS NOT NULL
) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT referred_to, referred_to_count, rownum r
  FROM my_table
  WHERE referred_to IS NOT NULL
  AND referred_to_count IS NOT NULL
) t2
ON t1.r = t2.r
```

An alternative would be to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function as suggested by [JamesZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30872751/521799), but I suspect that would be a bit slower:

```
SELECT referred_from, referred_from_count, referred_to, referred_to_count
FROM (
  SELECT referred_from, referred_from_count, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) r
  FROM my_table
  WHERE referred_from IS NOT NULL
  AND referred_from_count IS NOT NULL
) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT referred_to, referred_to_count, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) r
  FROM my_table
  WHERE referred_to IS NOT NULL
  AND referred_to_count IS NOT NULL
) t2
ON t1.r = t2.r
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have those as a 2 separate result sets, and add row_number() over (order by ...) to both of them, so that both of the results will have a number 1,2... for the wanted order.

Then join the result sets with the row number and use full outer join in case either of them can contain more rows.

Comment: And this is how you do it in SQL Server, the other database platforms might have some differences at least in syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to provide the query. It seems like you are trying to do something like :

```
select Id, Referred_from ,COUNT(Referred_from),Referred_to,COUNT(Referred_to)
group by id, referred_from,referred_to
order by Id,referred_from
```